# No se como instalar SDL de manera correcta

Tags: c

Para un proyecto tengo que hacer un pong en c, soy nuevo con el lenguaje por lo que  no entiendo como usar la libreria SDL (uso mingw y sublimeText). Cada vez que compilo algo, aunque sea la funcion mas basica de pruebas, me aparece un error tipo **" undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld devolvió el estado de salida 1"**

Alguien que pueda orientarme con el tema?

Comment: Por favor agrega el código para que podamos ayudarte

Answer (score -1):

En dónde sea que tengas tu SDL tienes que incluir la DLL y los libs correspondientes, por ejemplo yo tengo mi SDL en la ruta C:/

Entonces yo en mi proyecto copio la DLL en la carpeta de compilación de mi proyecto

Por ejemplo, si tu Windows es 64 bits, copio la DLL que está ubicada en C:/SDL/lib/x64 en tu carpeta de compilación para que funcione Y hago referencia a los libs que están en esa ruta

Por ejemplo, tu ejecutable se compila en ./compilacion
Tienes que meter esa DLL allí dentro de esa carpeta, te quedaría de la siguiente forma:

./compilacion

- SDL2.dll
- tu_proyecto_compilado.exe

Te diría como se enlazan los archivos .lib pero realmente no me acuerdo ahorita y no quiero darte una mala respuesta, llevo años que no tocó SDL ni Vulkan

Te recomiendo hacer un tu archivo .cmake, para no tener que estar ejecutando un montón de comandos cada vez que quieras compilar tu proyecto, entonces el CMake evitará que tengas que ejecutar ese montón de comandos para enlazar los libs

También te recomiendo esta otra librería llamada [MiniWin](https://miniwin.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Instalacion.html), es una librería en español y sencilla de usar si lo que quieres hacer es muy sencillo, tampoco digo que SDL sea malo, pero está librería está especialmente orientada a Windows.

Comment: Vale amigo, lo probare, muchas gracias c: